# Iteration order of for.in &ndash; not by insertion (any more?)

Tags: javascript, sorting, for-in-loop

According to my research, the order of keys in a `for..in` loop should be undefined/unreliable – but, if left undisturbed, should be in insertion order – but it's not:

I fetch this data object from the database, ordered by name:

```
var travel = {  
    '2': { name: 'bus',  price: 10 },  
    '3': { name: 'foot', price: 0 },  
    '1': { name: 'taxi', price: 100 }  
}  
for (way in travel) console.log( travel[way].name ) // => taxi, bus, foot
```

The keys get ordered numerically (in all of Chrome, Firefox, and Edge). Why?

And (since I was wrong) how can I iterate through them ordered by `.name`?

Comment: If you need them ordered, use a `sort()` on `Object.values()`.

Comment: i'm guessing there could be some sort of internal optimization happening that it looks like an array

Comment: yea - if you add a key that isn't a number, it works as expected

Comment: the upshot is that the order is **undefined** and should never be relied on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> According to my research, the order of keys in a for..in loop should be undefined/unreliable

Undefined, yes.

> - but, if left undisturbed, should be in insertion order

No, you were right the first time: It's undefined. Even in ES2015 (aka "ES6") and above, which do provide property order for some other operations, the older operations `for-in` and `Object.keys` are not required to follow the order defined for the new ones.

In those other operations (`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`, `JSON.serialize`, ...), the order ([defined here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-ordinaryownpropertykeys)) isn't purely insertion order: Properties whose names are *array indexes* according to the spec's definition* come first, in numeric order. Most major JavaScript engines have updated their handling of `for-in` to match their handling of these new operations (many already did treat array indexes differently, but they varied in terms of whether they put those before the non-array-indexes or after), but again, it's undefined, and you shouldn't rely on it.

If you want pure insertion order, ES2015's `Map` provides that, regardless of the value of the key. Objects don't.

Here's an example using `Map`:

```js
const map = new Map([
  ['2', { name: 'bus',  price: 10 }],
  ['3', { name: 'foot', price: 0 }],
  ['1', { name: 'taxi', price: 100 }]
]);
for (const entry of map.values()) { // bus, foot, taxi
  console.log(entry.name);
}
```

---

* [The spec's definition](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-object-type) of an "array index" is:

> An *integer index* is a String-valued property key that is a canonical numeric String (see 7.1.16) and whose numeric value is either +0 or a positive integer ≤ 2<sup>53-1</sup>. An *array index* is an integer index whose numeric value *i* is in the range +0 ≤ i < 2<sup>32-1</sup>.

Comment: Thank you for a fantastic answer! Map looks like my new best friend : )

Answer (score 1):

In practice, javascript object iterates by keys in insertion order *except* when keys are numeric.  This is probably caused be the need to make array iteration (arrays are objects too) ordered by key.

So, your choices are
- respect the standard and use ES6 Map or arrays of objects to guarantee iteration order
- make your keys always non-numeric and hope for the best

Comment: I don't like the "hope for the best" approach - too old for that : ) Map it is!